# send json in post to a server node

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, axios

This is the code I use to send a ready json in post using axios.

```js
const axios = require("axios");

const jsonObj = {
    serial: '090982037439', //string
    sensor_type: 'ciccio bello', //string

    value_registered: {
        value: 30, //valore
        unit_of_measure: 'celsius' ///string
    },

    value_registered_at: '29-04-2021' ///string 

};

const json = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/post',
    data: json
});
```

But I always get the following error (415) back.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise 
rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:11188) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Have you tried (assuming this is for web development) opening the network tab in the chrome dev tools?

Answer (score 1):

[415 Unsupported Media Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415)

1. [Looks like](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-make-http-requests-like-a-pro-with-axios/) axios don't need to stringify data (or that is optional)?
2. Try to set MIME type
3. 415 Response code means that axios at least sending data. So check problem at backend
4. `catch` error when response code is non-20X

```js
const options = {
  headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'}
};

axios.post(
  '/login',
  {
    firstName: 'Finn',
    lastName: 'Williams'
  },
  options
).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

415 means unsupported media type. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415

Make sure that the API endpoint supports json request. Good luck!